# How can I use built-in cginc shaders in my Unity3d project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, arcgis, hlsl, built-in

I want to know how can I use builtin `.cginc` Shader files in my unity's project ?
I just copy this files in my project Assets folder but unity does not recognize them !

does somebody knows how can I use this files ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.cginc files can be used inside the shader they are the include files for the shader.
You can use them inside subshader code like this

```
#include "UnityCG.cginc"
```

One use of these file is if you have some common functions that you want to use in different shaders write them in a cginc file and include it in different shaders you do not have to write those functions again and again.